# What is $\mathbb{R}^n$ called in words?

Tags: linear-algebra

Vector space over the reals? This doesn't make sense because obviously subspaces of $\mathbb{R}^n$ are also vector spaces that are also made up of real numbers.

Comment: Is is called the $n-$ dimensional real Euclidean space.

Comment: View the first sentence and more in [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_coordinate_space) Wikipedia article for "Real coordinate space"

Comment: I often just say $\mathbb R^n$ out loud.

Comment: @littleO: Yes, but exactly what words do you say?  I say "R-N"; is that what you say?

Comment: It's important to note that $\mathbb{R}^n$ is only a vector space after you've defined scalar multiplication and addition on it. Without that additional structure they are merely points, not vectors.

Comment: It does make sense to say “vector space over the reals”, it’s just not very specific. Most people will think of $ℝ^n$ if you include the dimension and put the definitive article “the” in front. In vulgar language, everyone just says “R to the N” or “R-N” as Brian Tung or littleO. More poetically inclined people may prefer to say “$n$-dimensional real Euclidean space”, as Kavi Rama Murthy suggested, but as CyclotomicField notes, this may convey the impression that you speak of an affine space. If you don’t mind being wordy, you may use “the standard real linear space of dimension $n$”.

Comment: @BrianTung Yes, I just say "R-N". Two syllables, sounds just like "are in".

Comment: I say R to the n.

Comment: @CyclotomicField: Actually they are not points until you define a topology on it (which by default will be the product topology for the standard topology on $\mathbb R$, of course). On the other hand, they are not “merely points” because they do have a structure; they are $n$-tuples. In particular, you can meaningfully talk about their components, without imposing any additional structure.

Comment: @k.stm Is "complex Euclidean space" a thing?

Comment: If the answer below answers your question, please accept it so the question does not remain active (-: .

Answer (score 5):

It may be helpful to expand $\mathbb{R}^n$ using the definition of the cartesian product as follows:

> $\mathbb{R}^n$ $:=$ $\underbrace{\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}... \times \mathbb{R}}_\text{$n$ many times}$ = {$(p_{1},...,p_{n})| p_{i} \in \mathbb{R}$}.

So $\mathbb{R}^n$ is, as the comments suggest, $n$-dimensional Euclidean space. Or more precisely, the set of all $n$-tuples of real numbers. We read the set $\mathbb{R}^n$ aloud as "*R-N*".